# Notepad++ Is there anyway to show recently opened files in Doc Switcher?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ has a document panel which can be enabled in the settings

> Settings > Preferences > General > Document List Panel > Show

This panel displays the currently opened documents. Is there anyway (plugin or otherwise) to view the recently opened documents here as well?

Answer (score 1):

For the next best thing you can get a drop down list when you click on "File".
The number in the list can be set with
Settings > Preferences > Recent Files History > Max. number of entries : nn
This list has the full path and filename for all recently opened files.